# How do i downgrade expo and install a specific package?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-community-netinfo, metro.js

Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - @react-native-community/netinfo - expected version range: 5.5.1 - actual version installed: ^5.8.0
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]

Im getting this above warning. is there any cli command to do install specific expo package? if yes then please provide it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Into your package.json file, update the version of **@react-native-community/netinfo** to the right one (5.5.1), and make a npm install again.

You can also provide the version by using the cli command :

```js
npm i @react-native-community/netinfo@5.5.1
```

Comment: This is correct - note that this works with `npm` install, not with `expo i package@version`.